# C++ Depth First Search (DFS) Implementation

Tags: c++, vector, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement the following DFS code described at Competitive Programming 1 book:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10
#define DFS_BLACK 1
#define DFS_WHITE -1
typedef pair<int, int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
typedef vector<int> vi;

vi dfs_num;
vector<vii> adj(MAX);

void dfs(int u) {
    dfs_num[u] = DFS_BLACK;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)adj[i].size(); i++) {
        ii v = adj[u][i];
        if (dfs_num[v.first] == DFS_WHITE)
            dfs(v.first);
    }
    printf(" %d", u);
}

int main() {
    int v, e, x, y;

    scanf("%d %d", &v, &e);
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        adj[x].push_back(ii(y, 1));
        adj[y].push_back(ii(x, 1));
    }

    int numCC = 0;
    dfs_num.assign(v, DFS_WHITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        if (dfs_num[i] == DFS_WHITE)
            printf("Component %d:", ++numCC), dfs(i), printf("\n");
    printf("There are %d connected components\n", numCC);
}
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
Input:        Output:
9 7           Component 1: 0 1 2 3 4
0 1           Component 2: 5
1 2           Component 3: 6 7 8
1 3           There are 3 connected components
2 3
3 4
6 7
6 8
```

For the following graph:

[image: graph1]

But I am getting "Component 1: 3 2 1" then it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)adj[i].size(); i++) {
```

into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)adj[u].size(); i++) {
//                           ^ u, not i
```

[Live demo link](http://ideone.com/i2Z4mE)

Answer (score 1):

The overall logic seems ok, but I see some weird things in the details:

1. in line 17, the for-loop, should that be adj[u], rather than adj[i] ??

Other things I noticed:

1. Not using single-letter variable names would greatly help us understand your code...means you'll get more replies.
2. Your connected components will print in reverse order (3 2 1, rather than 1 2 3) because in dfs() you have the print after the recursive call
3. I question why you're using a pair in lines 31 and 32 when the second int is 1, and you never use it.

Comment: 1. That was the main problem. Solved as suggested by Piotr S. 1. Sorry about that. 2. Fixed that too, thank you. 3. Well the number 1's are supposed to be the weights but I'm just not using them yet